# Read more text expand. Currently loses formatting until you press "read more"

Tags: jquery

I am working on the code which allows me to add a "read more" link at the end of lengthy content. Once clicked it shows the rest of the content and expands.

The problem I'm having is this method breaks the formatting of the text until the "more" link is selected.

Is there any way around this? Id like to keep the text formatting before and after you click read more.

See the demo below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  length = 200;
  cHtml = $(".content").html();
  cText = $(".content").text().substr(0, length).trim();
  $(".content").addClass("compressed").html(cText + "... <a href='#' class='exp'>More</a>");
  window.handler = function() {
    $('.exp').click(function() {
      if ($(".content").hasClass("compressed")) {
        $(".content").html(cHtml + "<a href='#' class='exp'>Less</a>");
        $(".content").removeClass("compressed");
        handler();
        return false;
      } else {
        $(".content").html(cText + "... <a href='#' class='exp'>More</a>");
        $(".content").addClass("compressed");
        handler();
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
  handler();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 12px/1.5 sans-serif;
}

.content,
.content p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00f;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam suscipit veniam non <a href="#">magni similique</a>. Asperiores aut sapiente nobis porro ad provident eveniet eos aspernatur quidem iusto! Dolorum libero porro animi.</p>
  <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente aperiam voluptas mollitia laboriosam delectus <strong>possimus minus quaerat culpa</strong> eos corporis tenetur ducimus quo incidunt aspernatur doloremque unde nihil. Quis quaerat!</p>
  <p>Ea iusto obcaecati cumque quae numquam minima laboriosam porro sit a animi reprehenderit eveniet saepe aperiam optio nemo eos et. Eaque perferendis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed `});`. So, [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48645501/2) was indeed needed.

Comment: @PortalP edit was definitely needed - point of SO is that it should have the code in the question so that future visitors to the site can see what was wrong even if fiddle is down.  It's just as easy to make a code snippet as it is to make a fiddle so perhaps you should do that from now on when asking a question. If you do not post enough code in your question then your question is off topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
cText = $(".content").text().substr(0, length).trim();
```

to

```
cText = $(".content").html().substr(0, length).trim();
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZLgs/19/)

Comment: Hey thanks ZP... I donno how i didnt try switching the .text... Yay mornings.

Thanks!!

Comment: I am trying to use the above code for multiple divs but somewhere I am doing wrong..can you update the answer for multiple divs having same class

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using

`$(".term-description").text()`

What you need to do is

`$(".term-description")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Make the answer broader or use comment. [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)